# How to mock Jersey REST client to throw HTTP 500 responses?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, mockito

I am writing a Java class that uses [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) under the hood to send an HTTP request to a RESTful API (3rd party).

I would also like to write a JUnit test that mocks the API sending back HTTP 500 responses. Being new to Jersey, it is tough for me to see what I have to do to mock these HTTP 500 responses.

So far here is my best attempt:

```
// The main class-under-test
public class MyJerseyAdaptor {
    public void send() {
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        String uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://example.com/whatever").build();
        WebResource service = client.resource(uri);

        // I *believe* this is where Jersey actually makes the API call...
        service.path("rest").path("somePath")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).get(String.class);
    }
}

@Test
public void sendThrowsOnHttp500() {
    // GIVEN
    MyJerseyAdaptor adaptor = new MyJerseyAdaptor();

    // WHEN
    try {
        adaptor.send();

        // THEN - we should never get here since we have mocked the server to
        // return an HTTP 500
        org.junit.Assert.fail();
    }
    catch(RuntimeException rte) {
        ;
    }
}
```

I am familiar with Mockito but have no preference in mocking library. Basically if someone could just tell me which classes/methods need to be mocked to throw a HTTP 500 response I can figure out how to actually implement the mocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
WebResource service = client.resource(uri);

WebResource serviceSpy = Mockito.spy(service);

Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException("500!")).when(serviceSpy).get(Mockito.any(String.class));

serviceSpy.path("rest").path("somePath")
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).get(String.class);
```

I don't know jersey, but from my understanding, I think the actual call is done when get() method is invoked.
So you can just use a real WebResource object and replace the behavior of the `get(String)` method to throw the exception instead of actually execute the http call.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing a Jersey web application... and we throw WebApplicationException for HTTP error responses. You can simply pass the response code as the constructor-parameter. For example,

```
throw new WebApplicationException(500);
```

When this exception is thrown server-side, it shows up in my browser as a 500 HTTP response.

Not sure if this is what you want... but I thought the input might help! Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks @ktm5124 (+1) - but I need to mock this from the *client-side*. This is a 3rd party API that I'm hitting so I can't mock anything in the server code. Thanks again!

Comment: Is ClientHandlerException the class you need? I haven't worked with Jersey client, so I might be in the dark here. By the way, thanks for putting me above the mark of the devil!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to simulate a 500 response with the following code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class JerseyTest {

    @Mock
    private Client client;
    @Mock
    private WebResource resource;
    @Mock
    private WebResource.Builder resourceBuilder;

    @InjectMocks
    private Service service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }


    @Test
    public void jerseyWith500() throws Exception {

        // Mock the client to return expected resource
        when(client.resource(anyString())).thenReturn(resource);
        // Mock the builder
        when(resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).thenReturn(resourceBuilder);

        // Mock the response object to throw an error that simulates a 500 response
        ClientResponse c = new ClientResponse(500, null, null, null);

        // The buffered response needs to be false or else we get an NPE
        // when it tries to read the null entity above.
        UniformInterfaceException uie = new UniformInterfaceException(c, false);
        when(resourceBuilder.get(String.class)).thenThrow(uie);

        try {
            service.get("/my/test/path");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Your assert logic for what should happen here.
        }
    }
}
```